# Generating Swagger for Map<String, List<String>>?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm using swagger 2.0 with Spring Java. I have some class like this.

```
public class Profile{

    private Map<String, List<String>> namesMap;

}
```

I know the correct swagger specification for `namesMap`:

```
namesMap:
  type: object
    additionalProperties:
    type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

But my problem is, when I try to auto generate the swagger specifications by the annotations, It fails to generate the above specification for `namesMap`. Instead, it shows an error telling ***it cannot resolve reference for List***.

Is there any work around where I can tell the swagger specification generator to generate the specifications for `namesMap` in the way I have mentioned above (by any swagger annotation or any other way)? Or any other work around to solve my problem?

Comment: can you show the code where you r using annotations

Comment: @pvpkiran I'm only using at controller level. And it recursively generate the reference definition for the model classes.